# Clang-cl.exe and constexpr depth

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, constexpr

I'm using Clang 3.6 with Visual Studio 2015 and I'm using this CRC32 implementation to generate hashes at compile time:

```
#define CRC32(message) (crc32_<sizeof(message) - 2>(message) ^ 0xFFFFFFFF)

static constexpr uint32_t crc_table[256] = {
  0x00000000L, 0x77073096L, 0xee0e612cL, 0x990951baL, 0x076dc419L,
  0x706af48fL, 0xe963a535L, 0x9e6495a3L, 0x0edb8832L, 0x79dcb8a4L,
  ...
};

template<size_t idx>
constexpr uint32_t crc32_(const char * str)
{
  return (crc32_<idx - 1>(str) >> 8) ^ crc_table[(crc32_<idx - 1>(str) ^ str[idx]) & 0x000000FF];
}

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4100)

// This is the stop-recursion function
template<>
constexpr uint32_t crc32_<size_t(-1)>(const char * str)
{
  return 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

The problem is that when I use a string larger than 18 characters, `clang-cl.exe` complains:

```
constexpr evaluation hit maximum step limit; possible infinite loop?
```

I've seen some answers about setting `-fconstexpr-depth` or `-fconstexpr-steps`. I try to pass that options back to Clang with `clang-cl.exe`'s parameter: `-Xclang -fconstexpr-steps=10` but I get:

```
unknown argument: '-fconstexpr-steps=10'
```

The interesting thing is that I test the option with `clang.exe` directly and it recognizes it.

My question is: is there a way to set constexpr steps or constexpr depth with `clang-cl.exe`?

Comment: `-fconstexpr-steps`!? Did you try `-fconstexpr-depth`?

Comment: Yes, both. None succeeded.

Comment: Well, sadly it would seem that `clang-cl` is at least documented to support only the original `cl` options, with only a small subset of options unique to `clang` itself. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#id7 And I'm not sure `-Xclang` is meant to be used for command line options.

Comment: Although have you tried quoting the argument? `-Xclang "-fconstexpr-steps=10"`

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, no success.

Comment: Do not hesitate to specify `-fconstexpr-steps=1000000000...`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-Xclang -fconstexpr-steps -Xclang 10`

clang with gcc-style transforms `-fconstexpr-steps=10` into `-fconstexpr-steps 10`, two separate arguments.

In order to transform two separate arguments from `clang-cl` you should prefix it with `-Xclang` two times

Comment: I fail to see why this answer has zero up-votes. THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER!

Comment: This doesn't work for clang-cl v13.0.1.  For a start, the Clang arg is defined as `-fconstexpr-steps=<arg>`, so passing two separate args causes Clang to treat the last arg as a file (`no such file or directory: '10'`).  But putting an equals between them doesn't help (`unknown argument: '-fconstexpr-steps=10'`), neither does quoting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
/clang:-fconstexpr-steps=10
```

Added in this [PR](https://reviews.llvm.org/D53457), the `/clang` [flag prefix forwards](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#the-clang-option) the remainder of the flag text to the driver, bypassing the MSVC-style frontend.  Frustratingly `clang-cl` does seem to be aware of the equivalent MSVC flag (`/constexpr:steps10`, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/constexpr-control-constexpr-evaluation?view=msvc-170)), but doesn't know what to do with it!  You get a "argument unused during compilation" warning and the flag is ignored.

I don't know what the difference between `/clang` and `-Xclang` is, the PR and docs listed above differ in their descriptions, but my hunch is that they mean the same thing but `clang-cl` only acts upon the former.